# PHP Submit form to SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a form that currently uses PHP to insert the form entries into a MySQL database.  Is it possible to insert the results directly into a SugarCRM contact table instead of a MySQL db?

Comment: yes it uses MySQL but the table structure is not well documented and has many relationships with vague table names.

Answer (score 2):

Sugar uses underlying MySQL database for everything. If you haven't got 10 years to learn their logic about how they want you to interact with Sugar - just install SQLbuddy on your Sugar server, look at tables data and do queries as you wish. Nice and easy.

Comment: can you please explain more about this? I was able to do a complicated select query but inserting is another daunting task.. please help

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can dump your table as csv file.
then using sugarcrm accounts's import feature to import these data in to accounts module

Answer (score 1):

SugarCRM Contacts are several datatables in the (MySQL) database... (one for standard fields, another for custom fields, and then yet others for email address management)... as such, you should use the interfaces and features they've created to allow you to more easily interact with your data into the CRM.

for capturing leads, look into sugarcrm "Campaigns lead capture" and "Web Lead form"

for inserting data directly to other modules (i.e. contacts), you should consider using the soap interface/connector.
 - http://www.sugarcrm.com/wiki/index.php?title=SOAP_Intro_and_Practical_Examples

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the underlying db architecture of SugarCRM.  To answer your question, it is possible to use a web form to create/update records in SugarCRM.  econstantin mentioned, there is a contacts table, along with a contacts_cstm table for any custom fields that have been added to that module.  All custom tables have an id_c field, which can easily be joined to the id field of the parent table (example: LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm on contacts.id=contacts_cstm.id_c)

The SOAP client can be difficult to use, I would actually suggest looking at the REST client.  Unless you are familiar working with SugarCRM, you'll probably want to stick to using the Web Services that are available or the generated Web to Lead form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the rest api.